# SQLite + Javascript: execute multiple queries within each others functions

Tags: javascript, sqlite

The question itself may seem a bit confusing, but I'll try to explain it below.

So I have multiple queries that have to be executed, all depending on the previous one.

Let's say I'm executing query A, when that's done, query B has to be executed by using the data query A retrieved. After query B retrieved it's data, query C has to be executed with that specific data.

But while query B is executing, a FOR-loop is doing it's job and executing query C multiple times (query B finds 3 results, so query C has to be executed 3 times during the life duration of query B).

In the code below, I can try to simulate the situation with a more simplified form of my existing code (less details):

first function to be executed is QueryA() with a click on a button:

```
function QueryA() {
    db.transation(
        function(tx) {
           tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TableA',
               function(tx, results) {
                   QueryB(results);
               });
           });
}


function QueryB(results)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
    {
        db.transaction(
           function(tx) {
              tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE FIELDB = ?, [results.rows.item(i)],
                   function(tx, result) {
                       QueryC(result);
                   });
           });
    }
}


function QueryC(result) {
    for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
         console.log(results.rows.item(i).description); //description being a field
    }
}
```

The real problem is that all these function are asynchronous .. meaning they will be executed before the data has been retrieved and resulting in errors (I have left out the errorhandlers in this example, they are present in my current code, I just wanted to explain my problem).

I have no clue how the callback functions work, because I need to pull this off.
Any advice is welcome! (and please show it with some code, so I can understand how the solution might work).

Thank you!

And just for a reminder, I'm working with Javascript and SQLite. I know Javascript can be tough sometimes to work with, especially working with functions that take quite some time and executing others that are dependant on the previous one.

Comment: `SELECT TableB.* FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB WHERE TableB.FIELDB = TableA.somefield` Don't need two queries.

Comment: _"The real problem is that all these function are asynchronous .. meaning they will be executed before the data has been retrieved and resulting in errors"_ No. You pass to `db.transation` and `tx.executeSQL` a function that is called when the results have been fetched (hence the `result` object).

Comment: The callback functions are only executed when the data is obtained.JS is always single-threaded, so that's not the problem

Comment: Can you explain why the second is query is looping and never executing when it's called from within the first function? It exits after db.transaction and never executes the second query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. My teacher gave me the hint that multiple queries could be executed after each other, without using a function for each query.

I saved the results in an array each time, and in the resulthandler of the last query I did everything that had to be done (like create elements and that stuff). For example, I looped over each array, to show the correct info that was corresponding with each object in an array. (in my case, looping over the themes, then looping over the questions and checking if that question belonged to that theme, then looping over the answer and checking if that answer belonged to that question).

Everything worked out pretty good afterwards!

Thanks for the info on callback function though! I'll keep that in mind!